# Organizing/rearranging highest to lowest scores in python text file for a game

Tags: python, algorithm, file, text

**Relevant Background Information**

I'm developing a game in Python & Pygame for my high school Computer Science final. I have it pretty much all done. It's a zombie shooter game where a player finishes with a certain score and their name. I have the score saving to a text file. Every a new score is added it should look something like this in the new line:

Ronald 3680

Ronald being the name and 3680 being the score, a singular space in between the name and the score.

**What I'm trying to do**

How can I organize and rearrange all the scores in the text file from highest (top) to lowest (bottom).

**What I don't need help with**

Just so I can have a high score state where the player can check the highest scores in  their local save file.

**Addition**

I tried applying the answers to other similar questions but theres a lot of stuff I don't know and that I don't even understand how it works. So I'm resorting to a question.

**Sorry I forgot. Using Python 2.7**

Comment: What have you tried? You will have to `read data -> sort -> write data`. Just determine an appropriate data structure for reading the data in to make it easy to sort, like a tuple then use `sorted()` with a `key`.

Comment: Not answer to your question (which is already answered), but you should consider storing your data at least as a csv file. Its first step towards storing structured data.

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with pygame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting by reading the file:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as file:
    highscore = [line.strip().rsplit(' ', 1) for line in file if line.strip()]
```

This will open the file and then create a list containing all not empty (`if line`) lines, then it removes whitespaces at the beginning and end of each line and split it at the rightmost whitespace (just so player names with whitespaces are not split).

Then you need to (reverse) sort the highscore by the second element (the score):

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_highscore = sorted(highscore, reverse=True, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

and finally write that that one to a file again:

```
with open('outfilename', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(['{} {}'.format(name, score) for name, score in sorted_highscore]))
```

Comment: I did it, I put in the right file names. Doesn't work. Just makes a new exact file.

Comment: @KyleMeade Sorry, the answer had a typo. `itemgetter(0)` was wrong, it needs to be `itemgetter(1)` because it should sort by the score (second item).

Comment: I actually thought it was working. But now it's just randomly rearranging.

Comment: `with open('Data/saveddata/scores.txt', 'r') as file:
            highscore = [line.strip().rsplit(' ', 1) for line in file if line.strip()]

        from operator import itemgetter
        sorted_highscore = sorted(highscore, reverse=True, key=itemgetter(1))

        with open('Data/saveddata/sorted_scores.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write('\n'.join(['{} {}'.format(name, score) for name, score in sorted_highscore]))`

Comment: everything is text - so to compare numbers you have to convert them to integer `int()`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to load the existing file into a data structure:

```
scores = []
if os.path.exists(filename):
    with open(filename) as scorefile:
        for line in scorefile:
            scores.append(line.rsplit(maxsplit=1))
```

Now you have a list of (name, score) tuples.  Add the new one:

```
scores.append(("Your Name", 9923))
```

Then sort the whole thing:

```
scores.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda name, score: score)
```

Now write it back to the file.

Comment: TypeError: rsplit() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @KyleMeade: Well I'm sure you can "sort" that one out!  Don't expect to just spit every small error into SO and make your way to a complete program like that.